# Flask socket IO - asynchronous execution log delivery to client

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

We got some asynchronous jobs that can be scheduled and produce logs as each job executes. For example, say a job ID `100` is scheduled to run and the logs are stored in some database as the job executes. The client/browser is interested in tracking/seeing new logs as they become available say for the job `100`. The client emits an event say `log-for-run` with value `100` and that is handled by socketio.on at flask and can `emit` log messages.

1. How do we handle publishing of logs continuously as they become available (say it takes 10 min for the run to complete)
2. How do we stop/release gunicorn thread once the run completes and all logs are already emitted to client / user agent?

I believe below implementation may not be desirable

```
@socketio.on('read-exec-logs')
def get_logs_with_continuous_polling(run_id):
    created_at = None  # allow to get older logs for the first time
    while True:
        logs = run_log_repo.get_logs(run_id, created_at)
        for e in logs:
            emit('exec-logs', 'run={}, msg={}'.format(e['run_id'], e['message']))
            created_at = e['created_at']  # read logs that are newer to this timestamp
        time.sleep(2)
```

EDIT:

Or should the solution be handled in below way?

1. On `connect` event from client, spin up a background daemon thread
2. the background thread continues to look for new logs for a given run ID and somehow emit logs against the appropriate session ID so that it stays in the socketio queue waiting to be delivered
3. On `disconnect` event from client, shut down background thread.
4. also have a mechanism to shutdown background thread if there won't be anymore new logs or some longer time period has elapsed